# Value of type UIViewController has no member topViewController after Xcode 7 update

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9, xcode7

After I updated to Xcode 7, I get this error "Value of type `UIViewController` has no member topViewController." Anyone else run into this? Is `topViewController` no longer a part of `UIViewController`?

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Search,
        target: self, action: "addButtonPressed:")
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton

    if let split = self.splitViewController {
        let controllers = split.viewControllers
        self.detailViewController =
            controllers[controllers.count-1].topViewController as? ### Error heres
        DetailViewController
    }

    model = Model(delegate: self) // create the Model
    model.synchronize() // tell model to sync its data
    self.navigationController?.toolbarHidden = false;
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"Home", style:.Plain, target:nil, action:nil)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd have to make it explicit, so that it knows you are trying to get the `topViewController` from `UINavigationController` in Swift 2:

```
self.detailViewController = (controllers[controllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController).topViewController
```

Comment: yup, I ended up figuring it out. I put this:   if let split = self.splitViewController {
            let controllers = split.viewControllers
            self.detailViewController =
                (controllers[controllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as?
            DetailViewController
        }

Comment: `as? DetailViewController` the casting is very important. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Simple Do this 

extension UIApplication {
    class func topViewController(controller: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let navigationController = controller as? UINavigationController {
            return topViewController(controller: navigationController.visibleViewController)
        }
        if let tabController = controller as? UITabBarController {
            if let selected = tabController.selectedViewController {
                return topViewController(controller: selected)
            }
        }
        if let presented = controller?.presentedViewController {
            return topViewController(controller: presented)
        }
        return controller
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
UIApplication.topViewController()
```